# Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() on GAS - web app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to get the active user email so I can apply rules to each email. As I am doing this as an web app I am unsure how to get that info and paste it into a html page. I tried with this code and it works, but not as I want:

`var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 app.add(app.createLabel('Effective User: ' +   Session.getEffectiveUser().getUserLoginId()));
 return app;}`

As I am unsure how to get it inside a HTML file i am asking for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your client side javaScript use a function like this to assign a value to the `user` variable ( in this case I declare it outside of the function to make it global):

```
var user;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getUserEmail).getUser();
function getUserEmail(userMail){
  user = userMail;
}
```

and in your .gs file (server side code) write a simple function like below that will send the user email :

```
function getUser(){
  user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Thx ! Glad it helped. Please think about accepting the answer.

Comment: Other question and sorry to be annoying. Is it possible to take that email from the jquery and pass it over to a var in the code.gs?